# npm install -g angular-cli apresenta erro

Tags: npm, angular

Antes estava apresentando uma mensagem de que o git não podia ser encontrado, dai reinstalei, corrigi o `PATH`, mas agora ele apresenta outra mensagem de erro, alguém pode me sugerir o que fazer?

> ```
> Binary is fine; exiting.
> C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
> de_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
> node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
> npm ERR! node v4.6.0
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
> npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its si
> blings' peerDependencies requirements!
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.
> 0.2
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler
> @2.1.0
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
> ```

Conteúdo do arquivo npm-debug (apenas a parte final):

> 276789 info install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17
>   276790 info postinstall angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17
>   276791 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\angular-cli-a36e756331c108c0.lock for C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli
>   276792 verbose validateInstall loading C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json for validation
>   276793 verbose stack Error: The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:125:32
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:268:7
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:142:5
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
>   276793 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
>   276793 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
>   276793 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
>   276793 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
>   276794 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
>   276795 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   276796 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
>   276797 error node v4.6.0
>   276798 error npm  v2.15.9
>   276799 error code EPEERINVALID
>   276800 error peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>   276800 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
>   276800 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0
>   276801 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Poderia postar o conteúdo desse arquivo : C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log ou ele é o mesmo do erro apresentado ?

Comment: Conforme solicitado @otaciojb editei a pergunta e acrescentei o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238556/npm-install-404-error/238581#238581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peerInvalid` é um erro de inconsistência entre pacotes. Ele pode ser corrigido deletando a pasta `node_modules` e rodando `npm update`, o que deve solucionar o problema pois o npm vai baixar os pacotes atualizados.

Se o problema for causado por um pacote global, rode `npm update -g`.

Comment: Fiz como você disse @gabriel-antunes mas o erro persiste [link]http://imgur.com/a/tKe1z[/link]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/tKe1z

Comment: Opa! Rode `npm update -g` para corrigir problemas em pacotes globais.

Comment: Tentei isso também, mas não obtive sucesso na época, estou tentando lembrar como resolvi para 'fechar esse caso'.