# npm install 404 error

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Comecei um curso de Vue.js e estou instalando um recurso pelo node.js porém estou tendo problemas com o comando npm, dá uma olhada;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que se encontra de errado no meu node nesse comando abaixo?

```
npm install vue vue-resource bootstratp font-awesome --save
```

Eu já desinstalei e instalei novamente o node e nada!

OBS: estou usando Windows.

Comment: O erro também aparece se testares somente `npm install --save bootstrap`? já testaste com o yarn? (`yarn add bootstrap`)

Comment: esse comando que você me passou não funcionou, e como faço para o utilizar com o Yarn?

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/ e depois `yarn add bootstrap`

Comment: eu estou fazendo um curso que no qual ele está usando o npm, se eu instalar o yarn poderei usar o mesmo comando que uso no npm no yarn?

Comment: O `npm` usa a API `install` e o `yarn` usa o `add`, mas de resto são praticamente iguais. Mas se conseguires instalar o `bootstrap` com o `yarn` podes continuar com o `npm` e seguir o curso como está.

Comment: Não fique chateado, mas vou tentar fazer funcionar o npm, mas se eu conseguir eu posto aqui o que conseguir resolver.

Comment: Claro que não fico chateado :) O melhor é o npm funcionar. Isso deve ser um problema intermitente que vai desaparecer. A ideia era testar o yarn para saber se funciona e eventualmente não ficares bloqueado aí.

Answer (score 1):

E só digitar esse comando que vai resolver o problema.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```